# Data Center Modeling and Simulation Using OMNeT++ paper

Tags: simulation, omnet++

my last codes are here:

```
import ned.IBidirectionalChannel;
import inet.nodes.inet.StandardHost;
import inet.nodes.inet.Router;
import inet.networklayer.autorouting.ipv4.FlatNetworkConfigurator;
import inet.nodes.ethernet.Eth10M;
import inet.nodes.ethernet.Eth100M;

package threetierdc;
module Rack
{
    parameters:
        int N @prompt(“ Nodes per rack ”);
        @display("bgb=406,179");
    gates:
        inout iogate[];
    submodules:
        ComputingServer[N]: StandardHost {

        }
        AccessRouter: Router {
            @display("p=278,50");
        }
    connections:
        for i=0.. N-1 {
            AccessRouter.ethg++ <--> Eth10M <--> 

ComputingServer[i].ethg++;

        }
        AccessRouter.ethg++ <--> iogate++;

}
network ThreeTierDatacenter
{
    parameters:
int N =default(1);
 int AGR =default(2);
 int CR =default(4);


submodules:
AGRouter[AGR]: Router;
CRouter[CR]: Router;
Racks[N]: Rack;
Configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator;
connections allowunconnected:
for i=0..CR-1, for j= 0.. AGR-1{CRouter[i].ethg++  <--> Eth100M <--> AGRouter[j].ethg++; }
for i=0..0, for j=1 ..1 { AGRouter[i].ethg++ <-->  Eth100M <--> AGRouter[j].ethg++; }
for i=0.. AGR-1 , for j=0..N-1 {AGRouter[i].ethg++ <-->  Eth100M <-->  Racks[j].iogate++  ;}  
}
```

i got this error:
Error in module (cModule)ThreeTierDataCenter.Racks0during networksetup:Gate'ThreeTierDataCenter.Racks[0].iogate$i[1](http://sameekhan.org/pub/M_K_2015_BC_KZ.pdf)'is not connected to a submodule(or internally to another gate of the same module).
I used this paper step by step :
[Data Center Modeling and Simulation Using OMNeT++](http://sameekhan.org/pub/M_K_2015_BC_KZ.pdf) AsadW. Malik and Samee U. Khan

Comment: _"i can't work with code correctly .sorry"_ Would you mind to elaborate about your actual errors plese? There's no way to diagnose your problems without a concise code sample.

Comment: thanks for reply . i will show u by picture :

Comment: _"i will show u by picture "_ Please no! Provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No one here is happy with pictures (that's why you're restricted to post pictures).

Comment: ok . it's the error .

Comment: _"It's the error"_ what please? Post error messages text verbatim in your question please, and relate it to particular code lines.

Comment: sorry . it's the error .

Error in module (cModule)
ThreeTierDatacenter (id=1) during
network setup:
(cGate)ThreeTierDatacenter.AGRouters[0].ethg$o[2]: connectTo();
gate already connected, at /home/mamad/omnetpp-4.6/samples/ThreeTierDC/NetworkDefination.ned:60.

Comment: You [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30277584/edit), I'll ignore anything else.

Comment: sorry .my english isn't so good.what am i suppose to do now?

Comment: _"sorry .my english isn't so good"_ Sorry, what has this to do with your english speaking capabilities? You post the error messages verbatim (and readable) in your question?

Comment: i did .end of line i added the Error .

Comment: dear @mohamad--figo in order to get proper feedback in stackOverflow you will need to present your problem in a nice fashion, otherwise we can not get enough context to help you... obviously it will take you time until you get used. Have you tried the TicToc tutorial to understand first how OMNeT++ works?

Comment: thanks for reply.no cause i'm very busy right now and i only want to implement the paper(i thought it's easy!!) i started step by step from this paper :Data Center Modeling and Simulation
Using OMNeT++ AsadW. Malik and Samee U. Khan for my presention.and i only used c++ in 1sem after C .my only programming Language is java but because i did'n see any gui network simulator based java ! i had to choose omnet++ .if i had time yes but at this moment no .stack was and is only my hope.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that you have already connected the output `ethg` port of `AGRouters[0]` to somewhere.

In this section of the `.ned`:

```
 for i=0..1, for j=0..1
 {
     AGRouters[i].ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> AGRouters[j].ethg++; 
 }
```

1. for `i=0` and `j=0` , you connect `ethg++` of `AGRouters[0]` first to itself (`AGRouters[0]`)
2. for `i=0` and `j=1` , you connect `ethg++` of `AGRouters[0]` to`AGRouters[1]`
3. for `i=1` and `j=0` , you connect `ethg++` of `AGRouters[1]` to`AGRouters[0]`
4. for `i=1` and `j=1` , you connect `ethg++` of `AGRouters[1]` to itself (`AGRouters[1]`)

I really doubt **1)** and **4)** are what you really want to achieve

---

```
network ThreeTierDatacenter
{
Parameter:
    int N = default(4);
    int AGR= default(4);
    int CR= default(2);
Submodules:
    AGRouters[AGR]: Router;
    CRouter[CR]: Router;
    Racks[N]: Rack;
Configurator: FlatNetworkConfigurator;
Connections allowunconnected:   // <<<<<<<<<<<< you are missing this 
for i=0..CR-1, for j= 0.. AGR-1{
CRouter[i].ethg++ <––> Eth100M <––> AGRouter[j].ethg++;}
for i=0..1, for j=0..1{
AGRouter[i].ethg++ <––> Eth100M <––> AGRouter[j].ethg++;}
for i=2..3, for j=2..3{
AGRouter[i].ethg++ <––> Eth100M <––> Racks[j].iogate++;}
}
```

Comment: as you can see.i want to get number of nodes from user .the complete scenario is :i want to create simple data center base of 4 factor : nodes,Core routers and aggregate routers AND Racks per nodes.racks must contain ars,and ar should connect to cr .by these every rack must see nodes!

Comment: @mohamad--figo you are missing `connections allowunconnected` after `Configurator : FlatNetworkConfigurator;` -- replace `connections` with `connections allowunconnected`... that might help

Comment: thanks @user4786271,the codes above are'nt complete.if U have paper,U can see the All codes.U right the code above not same as paper .i wrote all the code in my omnet++ exactly same as paper with Connections allowunconnected and other parts.as u saw i didn't any mention about omnet.ini but it is in the paper .tomorrow i will try again to test and report it here.by the way thanks for your time .